# When adding new product programmatically to existing Cart in Magento 2, product price is 0

Tags: php, magento, magento2

**My goal:**

```
Magento 2.2.5
```

If the customer checked to [Add Shopping Bag] option then click [Proceed to Purchase], I'll add the [Shopping Bag] product to cart and redirect to confirm page.

[Cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvuve.png) 　→　[Confirm page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oHhb.png)

---

**Source Code:**

```
public function addShoppingBag()
{
    $shoppingBagSku = $this->helper->getShoppingBagSku();
    $shoppingBagId = $this->productRepository->get($shoppingBagSku)->getId();
    $shoppingBagProduct = $this->productFactory->create()->load($shoppingBagId);
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $params = array(
        'product' => $shoppingBagProduct->getId(),
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => intval($shoppingBagProduct->getPrice())
    );

    $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $request->setData($params);
    $quote->addProduct($shoppingBagProduct, $request);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
    $quote->collectTotals();
}
```

---

**Problem:**

I checked **quote_item** table, product was added but all attributes related to price are 0.
**quote_address_item** table is fine, all prices are correct. The problem is only with quote_item.

---

**The things I tried**

```
$this->cart->addProduct($shoppingBagProduct, $request);
$this->cart->save();
$this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```

The quote_item price will be updated, but it will redirect to Cart page again because of the following code:

/magento2/source/vendor/magento/module-multishipping/Controller/Checkout.php

```
if ($this->_getCheckoutSession()->getCartWasUpdated(true)
    &&
    !in_array($action, ['index', 'login', 'register', 'addresses', 'success'])
) {
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_getHelper()->getCartUrl());
    $this->_actionFlag->set('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    return parent::dispatch($request);
}
```

When I try to:

```
setCartWasUpdated(false)
```

It redirects to Confirm page as I want, but the quote_item price is still 0.

System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout >  After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart is set to No

---

**Question:**

I searched a lot the same problem in google but no luck to archive my goal.
May be I'm missing something here, any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you for reading my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to set multishiping = false before add product.

```
$quote->setIsMultiShipping(false);
$quote->addProduct($this->getShoppingBagProduct(), $quantity);
```

Answer (score -1):

as i promised to you, I'll try to help you here this way ^^
So, first of all, you should definitly refactor you're whole method body. You're doing a lot of stuff more than once ^^

I can show you here an example of doing it in a magento way (untested ^^)

```
<?php

class MyCustomAdd
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $cartItemInterfaceFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $cartItemRepository;
    /**
     * I assume, that this is this class!
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory $cartItemInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->cartItemInterfaceFactory = $cartItemInterfaceFactory;
        $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException The specified cart does not exist.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException The specified item could not be saved to the cart.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException The specified item or cart is not valid.
     */
    public function addShoppingBagToCart()
    {
        $shippingBagSku = "coole_product_sku";
        $quoteId = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();

        $cartItem = $this->cartItemInterfaceFactory->create(['data' => [
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface::KEY_SKU      => $shippingBagSku,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface::KEY_QTY      => 1,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface::KEY_QUOTE_ID => $quoteId
        ]]);

        $this->cartItemRepository->save($cartItem);
    }
}
```

You may implement my custom fix for the CartItemRepository like i did it in the Github Issue.

Greetz,
Ulf

Comment: It is not working, when I debug, the shipping address only contain 1 product `shippingAddress->getAllItems()` → return 1 , the shopping product is not there. So I think that is problem. I tried to add item to address like this way: `shippingAddress->addItem($item)` but it not working.